# nodejs debug - save state of the script (with all objects and var values) and use it on next run

Tags: javascript, node.js, appium, webdriver-io

When I run the script, my application first creates an object that I will use in all my applications.

Object creation takes up to 10 seconds.  So when I try to test any new piece of code, I have to wait 10 seconds each time.

The app is going to be big enough, I can't wait that long when I add a new line of code.  How to deal with this?  Is there a way to save the state of the script from some point and run it every time from the point with this "heavy" object already initialized.

Comment: use a mock object and hardcode it in development instead of going through a "heavy" procedure to construct one

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that heavy object is something that will not change often, you could try
exporting it like this

```
const heavyObj = {};
module.exports = heavyObj ;
```

After that import the object wherever you need

```
const heavyObj = require('./data.js')
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, friend! Heavy object is a "client" instance of the connection to android device. This connection takes ~10 seconds. So when I add something new to code I have to wait 10 seconds before the connection is established. If I will not find any solutions it's gonna be like 1000 x 10seconds, too much waiting :)